# Prolog Outputting True and False

Tags: prolog

I have seen similar questions asked regarding prolog outputting true and false at the same time. People have suggested using the cut operator (!) or "once". I understand why prolog is producing true and false, and I understand how the cut operator works but I just don't know where to put it. Anyways this is my code(I wrote it on notepad++):

```
is_classroom_occupied(mon, 8, 8_348).
is_classroom_occupied(wed, 8, 8_348).
is_classroom_occupied(fri, 8, 8_348).
is_classroom_occupied(mon, 12, 9_285).
is_classroom_occupied(wed, 12, 9_285).
is_classroom_occupied(fri, 12, 9_285).
is_classroom_occupied(mon, 2, 8_247).
is_classroom_occupied(wed, 2, 8_247).
is_classroom_occupied(fri, 2, 8_247).
is_classroom_occupied(tu, 5, 8_348).
is_classroom_occupied(thu, 5, 8_348).

is_classroom_occupied(day, timeslot, location) :-
    is_classroom_occupied(mon, 8, 8_348),
    is_classroom_occupied(wed, 8, 8_348),
    is_classroom_occupied(fri, 8, 8_348),
    is_classroom_occupied(mon, 12, 9_285),
    is_classroom_occupied(wed, 12, 9_285),
    is_classroom_occupied(fri, 12, 9_285),
    is_classroom_occupied(mon, 2, 8_247),
    is_classroom_occupied(wed, 2, 8_247),
    is_classroom_occupied(fri, 2, 8_247),
    is_classroom_occupied(tu, 5, 8_348),
    is_classroom_occupied(thu, 5, 8_348).
```

The first half is a collection of facts that show the day, time, and room number of my classes, and the second part is a rule. Here is an example query:

```
 ?- is_classroom_occupied(mon, 8, 8_348).
```

and it outputs

```
true ;
false.
```

But I only want it to output the first result and ignore the rest. I know I can do this:

```
?- is_classroom_occupied(mon, 8, 8_348),!.
```

or this to make the program work.

```
?- once(is_classroom_occupied(mon, 8, 8_348)).
```

I am writing my rules on notepad++ and then using consult on prolog to use the file that has all my facts and rules. I do not want to use "once" or the cut operator on prolog, I want to somehow implement it while creating the rule on notepad++.

Comment: @lurker Yeah. I am using SWI-Prolog. But even If I use a word it would not work.

Comment: Please show a valid example. From what you describe it does work the way prog is designed. If it has a choice point, it will search for more solutions and finally fail (display false) when no more are found.

Comment: @lurker That is the problem. I don't want it to search for another solution, I just want it to stop searching after the first solution has been found.

Comment: Simply press `RET` after the first solution is reported: Prolog then stops searching for further solutions. The exact details depend on your Prolog system, of course. For example, in some systems, you press `a` to abort the search for further solutions.

Comment: @lurker: `8_348` is [a valid SWI-Prolog number](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=digitgroupsyntax).

Comment: @gniourg_gniourf thanks. I use GNU prolog a lot so didn't realize that. In GNU it's invalid.

Comment: Your rule is at least weird since it contains constants in the head, not variables.

Comment: @mat is possible to just implement it on (notepad++ ) the actual rule rather than having to press a button every time on Prolog?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Even if I use variables it would tell me they are singleton variables.

Comment: @ElPsyCongroo: but you do not need to specify a rule (based on the body of your rule), I think it you should ommit it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to wrap `is_classroom_occupied` into another predicate who will perform check whether a classroom is occupied and will succeed at most once.

```
check_classroom_occupied(Day, Timeslot, Location) :- 
    is_classroom_occupied(Day, Timeslot, Location), !.
```

Now when you consult the file, you can use `check_classroom_occupied` instead of `is_classroom_occupied`.

It may be possible to cleverly rewrite `is_classroom_occupied` so that it takes advantage of clause indexing to succeed at most once, but given your example data this seems to be difficult...

Also, as noted by [Willem Van Onsem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem), your last clause does not seem to make sense and should probably be deleted.